# How to convert an integer to fixed length hex string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an integer variable with max value of 9999.

I can convert to fixed length string (4-characters):

```
value.ToString("0000");
```

and I can convert it to hex:

```
value.ToString("X");
```

I want to convert it to a hex string of four characters (padded with 0 at the left if the value is converted to less than four digits hex value). I tried the following which didn't work.

```
value.ToString("0000:X");
```

OK, I can check the length of hex string and pad left with zeros.

But is there any straightforward way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use a number after the X format specifier to specify the left padding : `value.ToString("X4")`

Answer (score 8):

```
String.Format( "{0:X2}", intValue)
```

Comment: This will not be fixed length, it does not include leading 0's.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another method, 
You can define a function and pass it 2 values, one the actual number and the second is the max length to fix.
i.e.

```
public string FixZero(string str, int maxlength)
{
    string zero = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    int length = str.Length;
    int diff = maxlength- length;
    string z = zero.Substring(1, diff);
    z = z + str;
    return z;
}
```

you need integers in the format 0012, FixZero("12", 4)
or for 0001234, FixZero("1234", 7)

Comment: I notified you [back on Nov 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011572/how-to-load-data-using-jquery-and-json/13238275#comment18035497_13238275) about the requirement that links to your own site contain a disclosure from you, yet you have failed to do so, again.