# combine string.format arguments

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I want to generate a 4 character hex number.

To generate a hex number you can use

```
string.format("{0:X}", number)
```

and to generate a 4 char string you can use

```
string.format("{0:0000}", number)
```

Is there any way to combine them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an integer to fixed length hex string in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000966/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-fixed-length-hex-string-in-c)

Comment: my bad. didn't found the original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean: 4-digit hexadecimal number.

If so, then yes:

```
string.Format("{0:X4}", number)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
string hex = string.Format("{0:X4}", number);
```

? Alternatively, if you don't need it to be part of a composite pattern, it's simpler to write:

```
string hex = number.ToString("X4");
```