# Format string to fixed length in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert an integer to fixed length hex string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000966/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-fixed-length-hex-string-in-c)

I need to format a range of UInt32 values to a fixed length hexadecimal representation. Formatting in hex is the easy part, but the resulting strings are between 6 and 8 characters wide. How do I format the string to always be 8 characters wide?

Here is an example of what I am doing currently:

```
string valueA = Convert.ToString(UInt32.MaxValue, 16); // result is "ffffffff"
string valueB = Convert.ToString(UInt32.MinValue, 16); // result is "0", i want "00000000"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx):

> ```
> Console.WriteLine("{0:D8} {0:X8}", intValue);
> // or
> Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", intValue.ToString("D8"), intValue.ToString("X8"));
> ```

Yields `01023983` and `000F9FEF`.